# GRUB command is not working.

Tags: grub2

After upgrading from 12.10 to 14.04 grub command is not working, windows is getting frizzy.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Please explain how you are trying to command grub, and in what way is it not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be due to incompatible use of grub with the previous version, in this case please try with the below command by entrying through recovery mode,

```
sudo os-prober

sudo update-grub
```

Hope this helps.